# Removing index.php causes Not Found error on secondary pages

Tags: craft-pro

I'm moving an existing site to the new server and spent a couple of days trying to make this work.

Home page of the site loads just fine. Other pages load too if I add /index.php/ to the url. Otherwise I get 'Not Found' error.

Have gone through all the suggestions here: https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php, here: https://craftcms.com/support/why-index.php, and here: https://craftcms.com/support/enable-path-info. Everything checks out.

My .htaccess in /public_html:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

I'm on a clean install of Apache server. Made sure I have all the required extensions and config matches suggestions on the Craft site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @brad-bell - his comment on another post pointed me in the right direction. I thought that I already checked on mode_rewrite but I didn't.

> The Apache mod_rewrite module wasn't installed, so the  block of Craft's default .htaccess file was being
>   skipped not allowing index.php to be rewritten in the URL.

Enabling mod_rewrite solved the issue.